# getting more than 1000 object from s3 bucket on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have to write a rails task for getting files from s3 bucket but my bucket have more than 1000 object.

```
.
#Connection codes and configures
.
bucket = AWS::S3::Bucket.find('my_bucket')
puts bucket.size
# => 1000
```

this code just give me 1000 objects :( 
how can i get my all objects from s3 bucket ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the [S3 developer documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysPaginated.html):

> To manage large result sets, Amazon S3 uses pagination to split them
>   into multiple responses. Each list keys response returns a page of up
>   to 1,000 keys with an indicator indicating if the response is
>   truncated. You send a series of list keys requests until you have
>   received all the keys.

The response to a [REST *GET Bucket*](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) operation contains the *IsTruncated* element which plays the role of the above mentioned indicator.

To retrieve the next set of results, using the AWS::S3 library, use the last key from the current page of results as the marker in your next request.